# My goal is to run a Stepper through Python, but the values such as angular velocity and degrees are inputted by user through GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble with the Tkinter window not showing its contents and also storing the data inputted by the user into the stepper parameters. I got to run the Tkinter and the stepper in separate codes and it worked. But I'm not being able to integrate everything. Here's my code:

```py
import time
from tkinter import *
from pymata4 import pymata4

top = Tk()
top.geometry("450x300")
pins = [8,9,10,11]
board = pymata4.Pymata4()
board.set_pin_mode_stepper(num_steps, pins)
num_steps = Label(top, text="Steps").place(x=40, y=60)
angular_velocity = Label(top, text="Angular Velocity").place(x=40,y=100)
submit_button = Button(top, text ="Submit").place(x=40,y=130)
num_steps_input_area = Entry(top, width=30).place(x=180,y=60)
angular_velocity_input_area = Entry(top, width=30).place(x=180, y=100)
angularvelocity = angular_velocity_input_area.get()
numsteps = num_steps_input_area.get()

while True:
    board.stepper_write(angularvelocity, numsteps)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.stepper_write(angularvelocity, numsteps)
    time.sleep(1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: It was better the way you had it. This helps others see the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move quite a bit of things around. There may be some issues with this still as I am not familiar with all the context of the original code. However, hopefully it is good enough that you can see how to accomplish your goal.
I looked at the pymata4 module and there are some issues with what you are doing.

```py
from tkinter import *
from pymata4 import pymata4

top = Tk()
top.geometry("450x300")
pins = [8,9,10,11]
board = pymata4.Pymata4()

# These variables need to be declared to be in the global space.
total_steps = 512 # Total number of steps per revolution of the stepper motor.
motorspeed = 0 # The library does not use angular velocity, but speed.
numsteps = 0  # To change direction use negative int, according to the module documentation.
complete = False  # I added this to show how to stop running.


def actuate():
    global motorspeed, numsteps, complete
    board.stepper_write(motorspeed, numsteps)
    if complete:
        pass
    else:
        top.after(1000, actuate)  # This will run actuate after 1000 ms
    

def set_input():
    global pins, motorspeed, numsteps
    motorspeed = motor_speed_var.get() # run .get() on IntVar object instead
    numsteps = num_steps_var.get()  # run .get() on IntVar object instead
    board.set_pin_mode_stepper(total_steps, pins)  # it was num_steps?
    actuate()

num_steps = Label(top, text="Steps").place(x=40, y=60)
motor_speed = Label(top, text="Angular Velocity").place(x=40,y=100)
# Button requires a command definition or it is just for looks
submit_button = Button(top, text ="Submit" command=set_input).place(x=40,y=130)
num_steps_var = IntVar()  # These are tkinter built in. There is also a StringVar
num_steps_input_area = Entry(top, width=30, textvariable=num_steps_var).place(x=180,y=60)
motor_speed_var = IntVar() # and a BooleanVar
motor_speed_input_area = Entry(top, width=30, textvariable=motor_speed_var).place(x=180, y=100)



top.mainloop()
```

Let me know if it works for you. I didn't run this.

Comment: It states this error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1895, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Seven/Dropbox/My PC (Seven-PC)/Desktop/1.py", line 29, in set_input
    actuate()
  File "C:/Users/Seven/Dropbox/My PC (Seven-PC)/Desktop/1.py", line 17, in actuate
    board.stepper_write(angularvelocity, numsteps)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Seven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymata4\pymata4.py", line 1421, in stepper_write
    data = [PrivateConstants.STEPPER_STEP, motor_speed & 0x7f,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'

Comment: I don't know why its acting like this, I've tried to apply an int() to the variables, but still no success.

Comment: Also, the button is there to start the process the first time, then it lets the user input another value working as a reset, so no need of constantly checking, actually. In the future, my goal is to show a real time graph inside the same tkinter window, using a cvs file, but I'm just taking step by step. Also, thank you for your time and help... I really appreciate it! If you have an idea or a hint, let me know! @ShayneLoyd.

Comment: I changed the code. The link to it is on that pastebin URL. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It appears you may need to look at the pymata4 documents closer. Try the updated code. I would attempt to run, but I don't have one of these boards.